# Combining matrix of numbers with a row of variables

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to append $b$ as the last row for the matrix $A$ to form a new matrix $X$. I tried Join[] but it did not do what I wanted. Can someone help?

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
b = Array[a, 3]
X = Join[ A, b, 1 ] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: `b = {Array[a, 3]}`

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this is what I want though.

Comment: Why not?  It does just what you seek.  Or... `a = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
b = {Table[c, 3]};
Join[a, b] // MatrixForm`

Comment: I clarified my question. I want a new matrix X = [A;b] where b is appended to A.

Comment: Try: `Transpose[Append[Transpose[A], b]]`

Comment: @DanielHuber This adds $b$ as a last column to $A$, but I want to be the last row.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It works, but I still want to use b = Array[a, 3]

Comment: Do not include the `MatrixForm` in the definition of `X`, i.e., `(X = Join[A, {b}]) // MatrixForm`

Comment: `Catenate[{A, {b}}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: Try: `Append[A,b]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
Append[A, b] // MatrixForm
```